# How to specify DTExec parameter types

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

The project runs in Visual Studio and when started from the Integration Services Catalog.

When I run it from the command line with a parameter file, both of these lines:

```
/Par $Project::MaxRows;"250000"
/Par $Project::MaxRun;"45"
```

Cause this error:

```
Failed to execute IS server package because of error 0x80131904.    
Description: The data type of the input value is not compatible with the data type of the 'Int32'
Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider
```

If I take these lines out, the project runs fine with the defaults, which are the same as what is specified.

Any ideas on how to debug this?

UPDATE:
Fixed the issue by changing the types of the parameters to String and casting to int where they are used. But I'm still struggling with the "works when submitted from SSIS but not from command line" thing. I'd like to understand why.

EDIT: Changed the Title to reflect the actual problem.

Comment: Does it give the same error if you remove the "" from the numbers. I.E. `/Par $Project::MaxRows;250000`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
/Par "$Project::MaxRows(Int32)";250000
/Par "$Project::MaxRun(Int32)";45
```

There are some good examples of working with dtexec here -> http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231187.aspx